# how to specialize template class to get pointer from T, where T can be U* or shared_ptr<U>?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Consider the following template:

```
template<typename T, uint32_t HandleTag = '_ptr'>
struct X
{
    void * toPtr(T t)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    std::string toHandle(T t)
    {
        const void *rawptr = toPtr(t);
        std::stringstream ss;
        for(int i = 24; i >= 0; i -= 8) ss << char((HandleTag >> i) & 0xFF);
        ss << ':' << rawptr;
        return ss.str();
    }
};
```

where `T` can be a raw pointer `U*` or a smart pointer, e.g. `shared_ptr<U>`.

How to specialize `void * X<T,HandleTag>::toPtr(T t)` for the two cases?

Not even sure it counts as template specialization, as `U` is generic, so I'd have to introduce a template arg....

Tried:

```
template<typename U>
void * X<U*>::toPtr(U* t)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename U>
void * X<shared_ptr<U>>::toPtr(shared_ptr<U> t)
{
    return t.get();
}
```

but compiler said:

```
testptr.cpp:27:15: error: nested name specifier 'X<U *>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
void * X<U*>::toPtr(U* t)
       ~~~~~~~^
testptr.cpp:29:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 't'
    return t;
           ^
testptr.cpp:33:26: error: nested name specifier 'X<shared_ptr<U>>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
void * X<shared_ptr<U>>::toPtr(shared_ptr<U> t)
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
testptr.cpp:35:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 't'
    return t.get();
           ^
```

Comment: `uint32_t HandleTag = '_ptr'` looks freaky. What's that supposed to be?

Comment: I would have preferred a template string argument, while still supporting C++11, but I'm also fine with that aberration :-)

Comment: I'd go for abhorration :-) [Here's a replacement](https://godbolt.org/z/os7rv3P1b). The only "downside" with that is that `_ptr` will generate the same value on platforms with different endianess - if that could be called a downside.

Comment: Which c++ standard can you use?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by overloading the `X::toPtr` method with templates:

```
template<typename T, uint32_t HandleTag = '_ptr'>
struct X
{
    template<typename U>
    void * toPtr(U* t)
    {
        return t;
    }

    template<typename U>
    void * toPtr(shared_ptr<U> t)
    {
        return t.get();
    }

    ...
```

Comments on this solution appreciated.

Comment: Tou loose the constraint that `T=U`. You could write an overloaded free function template that converts any pointer-like type to `void*` and foreard to the free function in the member function `toPtr`